# How to use @SpyBean and @MockBean in a regular Spring Framework project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We use Spring Framework 4.3.14-RELEASE in out project. The structure of our application is as follows:

```
parent \
      module-one
      module-two
      ...
      module-n
```

Now we are trying to write some integration tests in one of the modules and we faced with the next problem: need to make spying on Spring Data JPA repository. 
In Spring Boot we have `@SpyBean` and `@MockBean` annotations, but they are not available in regular Spring Framework. We are not been able to migrate to Spring Boot.

We had an attempt to add `spring-boot-test` and `spring-boot-test-starter` to our project, but, what was obvious, it did not work: dependencies does not appear in the classpath.

And my question is: is there a way to use these annotations in a regular project? Or maybe other ways to spy Spring Data JPA repositories?

**UPDATE: Example**

```
@Service
public void MegaService {
    @Autowired
    MegaRepository repository;
    // ....
}

public interface MegaRepository extends JpaRepository<MegaModel, Long> {
   // ...
}

@Configuration
public class TestRepoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MegaRepository megaRepository(MegaRepository repository) {
        return Mockito.spy(repository); // of course, it does not work
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MegaIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    MegaRepository repository;

    public void testMegaLogic() {
        when(repository.findAll()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
             System.out.println("Hello, comrades");
             return invocation;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using just a `@Mock` and `@Spy` from the Mockito library?

Comment: @UroshT., it seems it will not work. We need to initialize a repository bean which will be injected into other beans and will under out control. Of course, `Mockito.spy(...)` does not work too, because the spyed instance must not be unnamed or interface.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use one of the mock library like  EasyMock, Mockito or power mock
- Spring also provide some packages dedicated to mocking, for more details please refer the link
  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#mock-objects

Comment: We already user Mockito. And let me check how to EasyMock wraps in spy type object...